# c++   structure initialization

Tags: c++, class, struct, initialization

How to initialize the structure in another class?
there is struct in first class:
first_class.h:

```
typedef struct
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
    }*v,*vekt;
```

and i want to have it in another class:
i tried in another_class.cpp

```
first_class:: v vector;
```

it doesnt work
where is problem?

```
\\========================================
```

the thing which i want to make is:
i have two clases, in one is placed this strukture, in another is methot which allows entering vector data to struct. I have to make the array of two vectors, but when i use array without ponter, just simple array of struct, it doesnt chenge struct variables.

Comment: @VJo: you are probably aware that `problem` is not an allowed word in question titles, no ?

Comment: @Edgar could you specify your question more clearly?  Your title asks how to have a vector of struct, and your question asks how to initialise a structure, where it seems you want to use the name of a structure inside another structure and just call it 'vector'.

Comment: @sehe Actually I am, but that was a joke. And the title still contains `prblem` in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct v
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

first_class::v vector;
```

I suppose there was some confusion with C-style struct typedefs.

Comment: but i need typedef, because futhermore in this clas i need an array of pointers to this struct.

Comment: Array of pointers to this struct would look like this: `firstclass::v *array_of_10_pointers[10];'. Depending on the usage scenario, it might be preferable to use a std::vector.

Comment: @EdgarBuchvalov `firstclass::v* arr[1024];` - note this is tagged C++, so none of the C limitations apply

Comment: not in another in the same first_class
there no way to iniatializa with typedef?

Comment: @EdgarBuchvalov: I'm confident that your entire design approach is flawed and will end in tears. Why don't you step back a bit and post your overall goal that you are trying to solve, and we can discuss some C++ solutions?

Comment: @KerrekSB: don't you think that is a bit strongly worded (both `design` and `tears` :)) @EdgardBuchvalov I'd certainly appreciate you show more of your code/the problem you actually are trying to solve.

Comment: @sehe: "need vector of pointers to this struct"... no, I stand by the wording, and I'll get the tissues. :-)